# Memcached logrotate file not being installed. Bug with memcached 1.4.2?

Tags: memcached, logrotate

My memcached logs are getting huge (in excess of 5GB). This isn't a huge problem in itself.  I can easily remove them.

I've sourced the problem to the `memcached 1.4.2` package not installing a logrotate file in `/etc/logrotate.d/memcached`.  It's listed as being included but when I used `apt-file list` to get a list of installed files it's not there.  Is this a bug or is memcached supposed to be rotating it's logs some other way?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are talking about ubuntu package as it is clear from your question (mentioning `apt-file`).

It seems that `memcached` package does not come with a logrotate file. I did not find on my system. It is not a big issue because you can create one easily. You can also complain to ubuntu maintainers.

Comment: Yes.  Sorry for not making ubuntu clear.  The logrotate file is listed as being included here: http://www.rpmseek.com/rpm/memcached-1.4.2-1mdv2010.0.i586.html?hl=com&cx=0:-:0:7870322:0:0:0: but maybe thats not relevant to the current package.

Comment: This is rpm package NOT debian/ubuntu package. So, they are not related!